# Fusioncharts live chart rendering problems

Tags: fusioncharts

I really like fusioncharts timeseries but I'm having couple of problems so I hope some of you guys can help me out with this:

1. Chart propertyes are ignored: plotHighlightEffect doesnt work (there is no highlighting when mouseover legend, nor mouse over individual line), Ancors are not displayed (setting attribute drawAnchors to 1 doesnt make any difference). And useMessageLog and showRTMenuItem, also doesnt work.
2. How to show all data points on the graph (without deletion of the oldest one on the left)? And define lets say to display 1000 points on current live view and other data can be viewed scrolling to the left?
3. When browser tab with the graph is opened the graph is drawing normally, but while you are viewing other tabs the graph doesnt like that and draws dashed lines :) How to fix this?
   [image]

```
const schema = [{
    'name': 'Date',
    'type': 'date',
    'format': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
},{
    'name': 'Current',
    'type': 'number'
},{
    'name': 'Temperature',
    'type': 'number'
},{
    'name': 'Mixer speed',
    'type': 'number'
}];
const chartData = [
    ["2020-10-10 08:59:00","1","20", "40"],
    ["2020-10-10 09:00:00","2","23", "40"],
    ["2020-10-10 09:01:00","4","27", "40"],
    ["2020-10-10 09:02:00","8","31", "40"],
    ["2020-10-10 09:03:00","14","45", "40"],
    ["2020-10-10 09:04:00","14.25","65", "40"],
    ["2020-10-10 09:05:00","14.44","67", "40"],
    ["2020-10-10 09:06:00","16.50","75", "40"],
    ["2020-10-10 09:07:00","18.90","80", "40"],
    ["2020-10-10 09:08:00","17.80","81", "40"],
    ["2020-10-10 09:09:00","15.50","74", "40"],
    ["2020-10-10 09:10:00","14.75","65", "40"],
    ["2020-10-10 09:11:00","14.70","63", "40"]
];

const fusionDataStore = new FusionCharts.DataStore();
const data = fusionDataStore.createDataTable(chartData, schema);

const chartConfigs = {
    type: 'timeseries',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    renderAt: 'chartContainer',
    dataSource: {
        data: data,
        chart: {
            theme: 'candy',
            plotHighlightEffect: 'fadeout',
            multicanvas: true,
            useMessageLog: "1",
            showRTMenuItem: "1",
            exportenabled: 1,
            exportFormats: 'PDF=Export as PDF|PNG=Export as PNG|SVG=Export as SVG',
            exportfilename: 'smaticGraph_'+(new Date().toLocaleString())
        },
        caption: {
            text: 'Cooking process overview',
            position: 'left'
        },
        subcaption: {
            text: '',
            position: 'left'
        },
        yaxis: [{
                plot: [{
                    value: 'Current',
                    connectnulldata: true,
                    type: 'line'
                }],
                orientation: 'left',
                format: {
                    suffix: ' A'
                }
            },
            {
                plot: [{
                    value: 'Temperature',
                    connectnulldata: true,
                    type: 'line'
                }],
                orientation: 'left',
                format: {
                    suffix: ' °C'
                }
            },
            {
                plot: [{
                    value: 'Mixer speed',
                    connectnulldata: true,
                    type: 'line'
                }],
                orientation: 'left',
                format: {
                    suffix: ' rpm'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

var chart = new FusionCharts(chartConfigs);

chart.addEventListener("rendered", function (_ref) {
    var chart = _ref.sender;
    chart.incrementor = setInterval(function () {
        if(chart.feedData){
            chart.feedData([getGraphOverviewData()]);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
chart.addEventListener("disposed", function(eventObj){
    var chartRef = eventObj;
    clearInterval(chartRef.incrementor);
});

chart.render();
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. FusionTime is a totally different and newer product than FusionCharts hence a number of FusionCharts features are currently not available in FusionTime. You can find list of supported attributes here: https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/fusiontime-attributes#chart-configuration-and-root-json-attributes
2. You can set the initial spread of the active window of the time navigator http://jsfiddle.net/srishti_fc/15ztv8er/3/

```
"xaxis": {
      "initialInterval": {
        "from": "2020-10-10 09:05:00",
        "to": "2020-10-10 09:11:00"
      }
    }
```

Reference: https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/fusiontime-component/time-navigator#set-the-initial-spread-of-the-active-window

3. Unable to replicate this problem in the above sample. Please replicate the issue and share the sample.